# How to send PUT request with HTTP HEADERS and a FILE with Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, onedrive

I am a newbie to Objective-C and please let me elaborate what I am doing...

I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive using PUT request.

PUT request must contain

*Http Headers*

[One Drive Documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm)

content-length **7919**

content-range **bytes 0-7918/7919**

and with these headers a file will be uploaded

```
PUT https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337
Content-Length: 7919
Content-Range: bytes 0-7918/7919

<bytes 0-7918 of the file>
```

**Given below are the screen shots of whole PUT request using Chrome POSTMAN**

I am trying to make a PUT request with given below headers:

[image]

and a file

[image]

Could you please guide me how can I do the above using Objective-C

**PROBLEM**

Everything is working fine with POSTMAN but when I am trying to do it with Objective-C, the file is not getting uploaded and I am getting the given below result:

> {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Declared fragment length
>   does not match the provided number of bytes"}}

**Objective C code**

```
-(void)uploadFile:(NSString*)uploadUrl
{
    NSString *urlString = uploadUrl;

    NSData* file =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [@"/Users/username/Desktop/s.sql" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

    NSString* fileName = @"s.sql";


//

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];


    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"bytes 0-7918/7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Range"];


    NSMutableData *putData = [NSMutableData data];
    [putData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Append the file
    [putData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [putData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileupload\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [putData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [putData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file]];



    // Close
    [putData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Append
    [request setHTTPBody:putData];


    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


}
```

Comment: I assume you are talking about HTTP requests here?

Comment: Yes @trojanfoe as you can see in screen shots i have attached

Comment: Only by noticing the URL scheme is `https://`.  You should make it more obvious in the title and text.  I also notice you are using a different content-type in Postman and Objective-C code.  Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to God Finally I found a way. Given below is the edited and working code:

```
-(void)uploadFile:(NSString*)uploadUrl
{
    NSString *urlString = uploadUrl;

    NSData* file =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [@"/Users/username/Desktop/s.sql" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];


    [request addValue:@"7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];
    [request addValue:@"bytes 0-7918/7919" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Range"];


    NSMutableData *putData = [NSMutableData data];
    [putData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file]];


    // Append
    [request setHTTPBody:putData];


    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(resSrt);
}
```